# Does using tokens break REST principles

Tags: rest

Does using tokens for authentication break REST principles, which is supposed to be stateless.

I have an application which is required to be REST and I stored some tokens in a database. Each time a user wants to do an action, they should get a token (by sending a username and a password) and send it to the server with every request.

Comment: What is causing your application to require `REST` in first place? REST is just an architectural design of your system interaction that if applied correctly decouples clients from services and therefore make them more robust towards server-side changes. You are probably confusing REST with HTTP though. If a client sends username+password or just a token is not of relevance to the server as long as the authentication is send alongside each request

Comment: Please use real HTTP authentication ("Authorization" header) with "Bearer" method (a synonym for 'token' in this context) — https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6750

Comment: @Roman Rest is a good design principle, but so is using expiring login tokens, which make the server no longer stateless.  It's a great question.

Answer (score 2):

No they, don't.

A key aspect of something like the authentication header is the fact that it's orthogonal to the request itself. It's a property of the request in the same way that a Content-Type header is.

How Authentication is implemented on the back end is not germane to the discussion as long as results of the requests that submit the header are consistent. There's no reason the process of validating an authentication header can't be a stateless process in and of itself.

The presence and content of the Authentication can certainly impact what a client receives from a request, from a 403 Unauthorized response, to a limited amount of content based on whether the client is, perhaps, using an "admin" token vs. a non-privileged user.

It's also in contrast to a Cookie, which represent Session state (which is not RESTful). This is because the two headers serve different purposes and offer up different application semantics.

Answer (score 1):

Authentication Tokens are a standard way of authenticating REST Clients.

Authentication token themselves do not beak REST principles as long as your API doesn't behave differently based on the Auth token passed to the API.

i.e. if 2 consumers place the same request with different auth token, and they are both allowed to perform that operation, the result should be the same.

You can find more info on REST API authentication here: https://dzone.com/articles/api-security-ways-to-authenticate-and-authorize

Comment: What if the 2 customers have different permissions (stored in the database)? Is this allowed, or it breaks REST stateless principle?

Comment: yes different level of permissions is also acceptable, what you want to try and avoid is custom code for each of the consumer and/or complex logic that depends on such permission

Comment: In other words you may want to define your permission on specific actions. 
e.g. 1 consumer may be able to `retrieve` and `update` a user, whilst an admin may also be able to `add` and `delete`
That way your application logic and your role-based authentication are separate and independent - updating your application logic does not break your role-based auth and vice versa

Answer (score 1):

No it does not break the rule of being stateless.

Why?

Because the server is not maintaining any session w.r.t the client. It is just validating the token provided by client and returning results based on that.

If its client that has to maintain any data related to the session (which happens in case of tokens since they are sent with every request) then it is not breaking the REST principle, it is still stateless since the server is not maintaining the session or data related to the session.

Hope that helped.

Comment: surely the server has to remember the token, and that that token is valid for some period of time? i.e. not stateless anymore

Answer (score 1):

It does break Rest principles because once the service generates a temporary token based on login credentials, the service is no longer stateless. The service has to check with itself if the token has expired yet (the token is part of the system state now), for each call made using that token.

One can't say the session at any point is independent of all the client's previous actions, because if they did not log in correctly, they could not even use the system.

But you should use logins and tokens, and break the Restfulness in this small way for security.